# Dynamically refer to a JS array using a concatenated namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following demo, clicking one of the unordered lists (`#Foo` or `#Biz`) should append three `li`'s  containing text from the corresponding array, either arrayFoo or arrayBiz. I'm having trouble dynamically referencing the correct array though, and I'd like to avoid a lengthy set of if/else statements in my actual project, where I may have anywhere from 5 to ~30 elements/arrays.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/peiftronica/m841o7ys/3/)

I'd like to select that array dynamically by building the namespace like so `listArray = (array + listName)` but that doesn't work. Is there any way to concatenate a raw variable name, even if it's not as concise as that syntax?

Ideally I would like to keep the arrays as-is, I don't want to combine them into a larger array-of-arrays, or transfer them into dictionaries, but if that's the only solution I'll certainly accept it.

```
<ul id="Foo">Foo</ul>
<ul id="Biz">Biz</ul>
```

```js
arrayFoo = [
    "first foo item",
    "second foo item",
    "third foo item"];

arrayBiz = [
    "first biz item",
    "second biz item",
    "third biz item"];

$('ul').click(function () {
    listName = $(this).attr('id');

    // hardcoding this var so demo works...    
    listArray = arrayBiz;
    // I want to set listArray equal to (array + listName)
    // but I'm not sure how. When working correctly,
    // clicking #Foo should append the arrayFoo items,
    // and clicking #Biz should append arrayBiz items.

    listArray.forEach(function (listItem) {
        $('#' + listName).append('<li>' + listItem + '</li>');
    });
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m841o7ys/6/
But I advice you to incapsulate your data to the object. see @RoryMcCrossan's answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you amend your arrays to be contained within an object you can access them via a string variable using bracket notation. Something like this:

```
var data = {
    Foo: [
        "first foo item",
        "second foo item",
        "third foo item"
    ],
    Biz: [
        "first biz item",
        "second biz item",
        "third biz item"
    ]
}

$('ul').click(function () {
    var $ul = $(this);
    data[this.id].forEach(function (listItem) {
        $ul.append('<li>' + listItem + '</li>');
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/m841o7ys/5/)

Comment: I'd like to try and avoid wrapping the arrays in an object, that's what I meant by I'd like to keep them as-is (though I do agree with you, and have seen this solution elsewhere). If you couldn't do that though, e.g. the arrays were spread over multiple files but still accessible by the `.click()` function, would this still be do-able?

Comment: Definitely. If the arrays are spread over multiple files you could still use this pattern by combining them using `$.extend()`.

Comment: `$.extend()` was the missing piece, that's perfect for what I need. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty way of doing it is accessing via window element.

```
var a = "Foo";
window["array" + a];
```

But I'd advise against this, the proper way is populating arrays into an object and getting it with key values.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this but it is some what like @Rory implementation:

```js
var arrayFoo = [
    "first foo item",
    "second foo item",
    "third foo item"];

var arrayBiz = [
    "first biz item",
    "second biz item",
    "third biz item"];
var arr=[];
arr['arrayFoo']=arrayFoo;
arr['arrayBiz']=arrayBiz;
$('ul').click(function () {
    listName = $(this).attr('id');  
    listArray = "array"+listName;// it will not refer to the declared array.it will be merely a string so can be used as key.
console.log(listArray);
    arr[listArray].forEach(function (listItem) {
        $('#' + listName).append('<li>' + listItem + '</li>');
    });
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul id="Foo">Foo</ul>
<ul id="Biz">Biz</ul>
```